# ADO: Analyzing Sprint performance

Tags: azure-devops

I am a PO leading a small development team for enhancements to our PeopleSoft Campus Solutions application for a Medical School.
We are using the Sprint functionality in ADO to assign stories from our backlog to the Sprint, create the relevant tasks for each story (mainly development, testing, deployment) and assign the tasks to resources who, in turn, provide effort values (original estimate, remaining, completed). We also make sure our capacity is properly set, with resources OOO time and school holidays configured to get an accurate team and resource capacity. The team updates their effort numbers daily to ensure we are tracking burndown.

While we always start the Sprint with the remaining work hours under team capacity (and the same at the resource level), we have historically left alot of remaining work on the table at the end of the Sprint.

My leadership wants to answer the question "Why was the work left on the table?". Of course, there could be MANY reasons, we underestimated the effort, we were blocked on a task (for example, we can't start the testing task until the development is done), the resource didn't actually have the calculated capacity due to being pulled into other meetings or initiatives, or (and I don't think this is the case) people were just plain lazy.

What reports/analytics can I leverage to help answer this question? Even just seeing a list of remaining tasks per resource with remaining task effort and with a total amount of work remaining per resource overall would be helpful, but I can't seem to find anything.

Any suggestions or guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Queries to find the remaining tasks(add `column option->Remaining Work`)  and save the query into Shared Queries.

There is a query results widget in dashboard to display the query in Shared Queries. Do not forget to add Remaining Working in widget.
[image]

Remaining Work:
You could refer to the document: [Adjust work to fit sprint capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/adjust-work?view=azure-devops#balance-work-across-the-team)

[image]

Comment: @Chad Farrow May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?

Comment: so sorry for the delay!  Your insight was extremely helpful!   What I'm trying figure out now is how I can show the completed work and compare against capacity... both at the team and resource level.  For example, Joe had a capacity of 50 hours in this Sprint and completed 43 hours of Sprint work.